# Is there a regular expression for finding all question sentences from a webpage?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some questions from a web site using BeautifulSoup, and want to use regular expression to get these questions from the web. Is my regular expression incorrect? And how can I combine soup.find_all with re.compile?

I have tried the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib
import re

url = "https://www.sanfoundry.com/python-questions-answers-variable-names/"

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
a = soup.find_all("p")

for m in a:
    print(m.get_text())
```

Now I have some text containing the questions like "1. Is Python case sensitive when dealing with identifiers?". I want to use r"[^.!?]+\?" to filter out the unwanted text, but I have the following error:

```
a = soup.find_all("p" : re.compile(r'[^.!?]+\?'))

a = soup.find_all("p" : re.compile(r'[^.!?]+\?'))
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked my regular expression on https://regex101.com, it seems right. Is there a way to combine the regular expression and soup.find_all together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of methods to find `p` elements containig a `?` it to
define a criterion function:

```
def criterion(tag):
    return tag.name == 'p' and re.search('\?', tag.text)
```

and use it in `find_all`:

```
pars = soup.find_all(criterion)
```

But you want to print **only questions**, not the **whole** paragraphs
from `pars`.

To match these questions, define a pattern:

```
pat = re.compile(r'\d+\.\s[^?]+\?')
```

(a sequence of digits, a dot, a space, then a sequence of chars other
than `?` and finally a `?`).

Note that in general case one paragraph may contain **multiple**
questions. So the loop processing the paragraphs found should:

- use `findall` to find **all** questions in the current paragraph
  (the result is a **list** of found strings),
- print also **all** of them, in separate lines, so you should
  use `join` with a `\n` as a separator.

So the whole loop should be:

```
for m in pars:
    questions = pat.findall(m.get_text())
    print('\n'.join(questions))
```

Comment: Surely this extracts the whole paragraph, not just an individual sentence? (This is of course also a flaw in the OP's attempt.)

Answer (score 2):

Not a big regex fan, so tried this:

```
for q in a:
   for i in q:
       if '?' in i:
          print(i)
```

Output:

```
1. Is Python case sensitive when dealing with identifiers?
2. What is the maximum possible length of an identifier?
3. Which of the following is invalid?
4. Which of the following is an invalid variable?
5. Why are local variable names beginning with an underscore discouraged?
6. Which of the following is not a keyword?
8. Which of the following is true for variable names in Python?
9. Which of the following is an invalid statement?
10. Which of the following cannot be a variable?
```

Comment: From [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Simple is better than complex.". Got my upvote. :-)